# Can I Calculate The Discharge of a Capacitor If All I know Is Algebra

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

Since my last post on Engineering-Beta, I have composed a few simple simple circuits involving capacitors(super-caps specifically), resistors and LED's.

The following image is of a branch from a circuit I designed,which highlights the discharge of a capacitor through a resistor and LED. I will be using this as a reference to all my questions:

[image: Circuit C1.3, Branch-B]

The moment That I allow current to flow from this circuit, Voltage will begin to drop, and current would begin to drop also. I know that the addition of resistance into the circuit can slow the loss of charge at the capacitor...

I wrote a bunch of stuff regarding all this, but it seems trivial now. Basically, I'm dealing with a rate of change that is not constant,  and I'm trying to find precision in my circuit, I would like to be able to calculate the time duration of the discharge but, I believe that:

"Calculus is concerned with things that do not change at a constant rate"
-*TheMathPage.com*

Sum everything up, all I know right now is intermediate algebra, and from all my google searches about this topic, they keep talking about derivatives and calculus. So, how can I figure out the rate of discharge of a capacitor? Or have I answered my own question already?

Comment: Check out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. That might be the stack exchange you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks a lot, been posting to this community and I knew that this wasn't going to get me the input I needed.

Comment: What is LED forward current? What is the LED part number?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena well the forward current is 25mA max, but I set things up the way I did to get the most observation time. You see, if  I use resistors that only restricted charge flow from the capacitor at 25mA, and consider that Q=CV, it wouldn't be much to observe, the LED would flash for about fractions of a second. The higher the charge capacity, and the higher the resistance, the longer the LED will be able to shine.  I  understand the "mechanics " of the concept of a capacitors discharge, but to be able to precisely determine the point in time when it will fully be discharged...

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena ..., as someone else has commented, I believe also that The precision of calculation lies in utilizing concepts of calculus to equate the varying rate of change for the quantities Q=charge, V=Voltage, and I=current. I'm not a mathematician, but the moment current is allowed to flow from the capacitor, I realize that Q will change, and Q=CV, thus V=C/Q, and V now changes, and I=V/R, so I changes, and so on and so on with every moment that passes. Based on this, the rate of discharge couldn't be something constant, thus Algebra itself wouldn't be able to provide a solution.

Comment: base on my calculation you have about 0.226 msec discharge time. I think you will barely see the LED switch on. I would limit the current to increase the time constant. But then if you limit the current to much the LED might not switch on.  BTW what are the part numbers for the LED and the capacitors.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Uh...something on the lines of "CO-Rode Kit, 5mm LED's". Let me know if you get a positive google search off of that. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the information provided I will try to compose a better answer

Answer (score 1):

Correct you need to find the discharge rate of the capacitor. Take a look at [Calculation of Discharge Time](http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/ELNACalcuDYNACAPDischargeTime_Jul2011.pdf). The equation constant current discharge equation 1. For you equation total capacitance is is 2000uf. Your V1 is 15mA(400)+2V

[image]

Below are some good references on this topic

References:

- [Mathematical treatment of charging and discharging a capacitor](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electrostatics/text/Capacitor_charge_and_discharge_mathematics/index.html)
- [Home / RC Networks / RC Charging Circuit](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html)
- [How do I calculate how fast a capacitor will discharge?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4951/how-do-i-calculate-how-fast-a-capacitor-will-discharge)
- [Capacitor Discharge Calculator - Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/-/media/Images/Supplier%20Centers/T/TT%20Electronics%20Welwyn/tt-electronics-capacitor-discharge-calculator.xls?la=en&ts=452828e7-5a3d-47a6-af87-1bece327a585)
- [How do I calculate how fast a capacitor will discharge?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4951/how-do-i-calculate-how-fast-a-capacitor-will-discharge)

Comment: This will not be a constant current discharge.  The current will fall with time, until at the point where there is 2V left on the capacitor, the current goes to zero.

Comment: your are correct, without datasheets and specifications this is good start. If you have any suggestion or a better answer feel free to contribute in the form of an answer.